# Fetch table data from a string and then insert into db

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have  a string which i am getting from UI after submitting a form. Its reading from a dynamic table present in the UI and then post submitting, it is creating a list of data like below.

[{"keyname0":"url","keyvalue0":"http://www.google.com"},{"keyname1":"year","keyvalue1":"2013"},{"keyname2":"bill","keyvalue2":"senate"},{"keyname3":"type","keyvalue3":"html"}]

i have two column in database. one is "KEYNAME" and other one is "KEYVALUE".
I want insert each value of KEYNAME and KEYVALUE into database.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Ugh. A "more flexible design than thou" design again :/ Can't you change what that UI sends to more sane JSON?

Comment: yes i can change but i am not sure how to prepare the list of data so that it will be easier to insert into database.can you post some sample list so that i can try to make the list?

Comment: Well, instead of "keyname"/"keyvalue", create a JSON object with the values of "keyname" as keys and the values of "keyvalue" as values. It will be MUCH easier to process, for one thing. Ie, `{"url": "http://www.google.com", "etc": "etc"}`

Comment: Actually its a dynamic table and each and every time i have to press the "add extra row" button which will create a new row to add a new pair of value. so there is no constant name.

Comment: Yes, so what? JSON bject member names can be any string

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson:

```
private static final KEYNAME = "keyname";
private static final KEYVALUE = "keyvalue";

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(theString);

String key, value;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> members;
Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> member;

for (final JsonNode element: data) {
    key = null; value = null;
    members = element.fields();
    while (members.hasNext()) {
        member = members.next();
        if (member.getKey().startsWith(KEYNAME))
            key = member.getValue().textValue();
        if (member.getKey().startsWith(KEYVALUE))
            value = member.getValue().textValue();
    }
    // check if key or value are null, if yes problem!
    // process key and value
}
```

Comment: thanks. I will try this and let you know. hope this will fix my issue. thanks again for your quick help.